# Opposite word for "teasing"?

Tags: negation, antonyms

From some sources, I know that teasing has multiple meanings and uses. In human interactions, teasing comes in three major forms, playful, hurtful, and educative.

I'd like to know which is the opposite of this word when used in the context of something as in:

- A girl I like **teases** me.

Comment: Can you describe what the opposite of teasing means to you? Not every action has a direct opposite. What's the opposite of "A girl I like eats cake."?

Comment: @Peter But that is not the same sentence as the original, anyway - "A girl I like teases me" and "A girl likes to tease me" - they mean different things. In the first version, the sentence includes the fact that the speaker likes the girl... the second sentence removes that piece of information and, instead, implies that the girl enjoys teasing the speaker... which was not implied in the first sentence. It's great when you try to clean up grammar and spelling but those clean ups should **never** include sample sentences.

Comment: @Peter - looks like it's from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teasing

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for the source, would not have thought to look there. Interesting that it says educative **teasing** (in tales instead of actions) is different in indigenous American vs Western children. It would seem to me that **The Boy Who Cried Wolf** would also fall into the **teasing**(example) category, or maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Many words have antonyms that go in different directions. For example, the obvious antonym for the word _hot_ is _cold_, but the word _hot_ has other uses and meanings besides temperature. _Hot_ can mean _contentious_ or _divisive_, for example, so the "opposite" of a _hot issue_ could be a _unifying issue._ To help you find an opposite word for _teasing_ in your sentence, we need to know more about how she is teasing you: playfully, hurtfully, or educationally?

Comment: Am I the only one thinking the easiest antonym - *praise*? You like a girl who ***teases*** you, I like a girl who ***praises*** me.

Comment: @MaulikV - I thought of a similar word - _encourage_. Your suggestion works as an antonym for some of the "mocking" contexts of _tease_ (e.g., _She was teasing me because of my sweater_ vs. _She was praising me because of my sweater_). However, if we say something like, _She was teasing me because my favorite team lost the championship game_, then _praise_ would not be a good antonym, whereas _console_ would be.

Comment: @J.R. As far as I *read* OP's mind, *praises* suits. Alex is *specific* about the sentence.

Comment: what's with all the downvotes on this?  It's a legitimate question and there is a good answer and possibly better one in the comments (praises).  Further discussion would have brought up whether it was bullying teasing or flirting teasing, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Teasing** is indeed a form of **interaction**, sometimes involving **tickling**  If a girl is **teasing** you it usually means she **likes** you.  As far as I know, **teasing** does not have an **exact opposite**, however

> **ignoring
>
>   blanking
>
>   dislikes
>
>   disdains
>
>   avoids**

would all be **opposites in action** of **teasing** though not specific to teasing, in the same way

> **tickling** <> **not touching**

are opposites, though **not touching** could also be used as an opposite for many other forms of **touch**

A clear example of the opposite of **teasing** is an often used **admonishment** by parents

> Child: Daddy, William is teasing me!
>
> Parent: William! Stop **teasing** Emma and **leave her alone**!
>   Parent: William! Stop **teasing** Emma and **be nice**!

Comment: I always thought, if X teases a boy, it means X harms a boy that makes the boy feel sad! for example, a boy who has received flippant remarks from the other students.

Comment: Indeed, it can make the boy feel sad (or anyone who is being teased), however the question is what the underlying intent is, many times it is just a way the **teaser** is trying to get attention from the **teasee**, usually amongst children

Comment: @Cardinal - There's _cruel_ teasing, which can be humiliating, as you describe, but there is also _playful_ teasing, which is generally good-natured, It's designed to make the other person laugh rather than feel sad.

Comment: @Cardinal **playful** teasing between the sexes can be a form of **flirting**, too.